# arrange vector in descending order

Tags: array, vector

im trying to arrange the vector in descending order but its not happening..

```c++
int fibonacci[15]={0, 1};
int a=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int i=0; i<=14; i++) //loop to create the array
  {
    fibonacci[i+2]=(fibonacci[i])+(fibonacci[i+1]);
  }

  //Now arrange in descending order
  for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
    for (int j=i+1; j<16; j++)
    {
      if (fibonacci[i]>fibonacci[j])
      {
        a=fibonacci[i]; //mux number
        fibonacci[i]=fibonacci[j];
        fibonacci[j]=a;
      } 
    }
  }

  for (int k=0; k<16; k++)
  {
    Serial.println(fibonacci[k]);
  }
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: `14` is the last `i` index, but you are still reading from `i+1` and writing to `i+2`. You should fix your bounds.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that what you want is a descending sort algorithm, but in the case of Fibonacci numbers you can take advantage that they are already sorted at the beginning. Here are different strategies that you can try :

```
/*
  SORTING IN DESCENDING ORDER
*/

const int nbElem = 15; // 24 max
int fibonacci[ nbElem ] = { 0, 1 };

void createFibonacciArray( int inputArray[], int arraySize )
{
  fibonacci[ 0 ] = 0;
  fibonacci[ 1 ] = 1;
  for( int i=0; i<nbElem-2; i++ )
    fibonacci[ i+2 ] = fibonacci[ i ] + fibonacci[ i+1 ];
}

void displayArray( int inputArray[], int arraySize )
{
  for( int i=0; i<arraySize; i++ )
    Serial.println( inputArray[ i ] );
}

void displayArrayReverse( int inputArray[], int arraySize )
{
  for( int i=arraySize-1; i>=0; i-- )
    Serial.println( inputArray[ i ] );
}

void reverseArray( int inputArray[], int arraySize )
{
  for( int i=0; i<nbElem/2; i++ )
  {
    int fTemp = fibonacci[ i ];
    fibonacci[ i ] = fibonacci[ nbElem-i-1 ];
    fibonacci[ nbElem-i-1 ] = fTemp;
  }
}

void inverseBubbleSort( int inputArray[], int arraySize )
{
  for( int i=0; i<arraySize-1; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<arraySize-1-i; j++ )
    {
      if( inputArray[ j ] < inputArray[ j+1 ] )
      {
        int temp = inputArray[ j+1 ];
        inputArray[ j+1 ] = inputArray[ j ];
        inputArray[ j ] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

void bubbleSort( int inputArray[], int arraySize )
{
  for( int i=0; i<arraySize-1; i++ )
  {
    for( int j=0; j<arraySize-1-i; j++ )
    {
      if( inputArray[ j ] > inputArray[ j+1 ] )
      {
        int temp = inputArray[ j+1 ];
        inputArray[ j+1 ] = inputArray[ j ];
        inputArray[ j ] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin( 115200 );

  // Create and display Fibonacci array
  createFibonacciArray( fibonacci, nbElem );
  Serial.print( "\n\nFIBONACCI ARRAY\n" );
  Serial.print( "===============\n" );
  displayArray( fibonacci, nbElem );

  // Solution 1: Display array starting from the end
  Serial.print( "\n\nFIBONACCI ARRAY STARTING FROM THE END\n" );
  Serial.print( "=====================================\n" );
  displayArrayReverse( fibonacci, nbElem );

  // Solution 2: Reverse array
  reverseArray( fibonacci, nbElem );
  Serial.print( "\n\nFIBONACCI REVERSED ARRAY\n" );
  Serial.print( "========================\n" );
  displayArray( fibonacci, nbElem );

  // Solution 3: Inverse bubble sort array
  createFibonacciArray( fibonacci, nbElem );
  inverseBubbleSort( fibonacci, nbElem );
  Serial.print( "\n\nFIBONACCI SORTED IN DESCENDED ORDER WITH BUBBLE SORT\n" );
  Serial.print( "====================================================\n" );
  displayArray( fibonacci, nbElem );

  // Ascending order sort array
  bubbleSort( fibonacci, nbElem );
  Serial.print( "\n\nFIBONACCI SORTED WITH BUBBLE SORT\n" );
  Serial.print( "=================================\n" );
  displayArray( fibonacci, nbElem );
}

void loop()
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it using bubble sort algorithm (which is most simple but inefficient)

```
int fibonacci[15]={0, 1};
int a=0;

int arraysize=2; // variable to store size or array

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for (int i=0; i<=14; i++) //loop to create the array
  {
    fibonacci[i+2]=(fibonacci[i])+(fibonacci[i+1]);
    arraysize++;
  }

  //Now arrange in descending order using bubble sort
  for (int i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
  {
    for (int j=0; j<arraysize-1; j++)
    {
      if (fibonacci[j]<fibonacci[j+1])
      {
        a=fibonacci[j+1]; //max number
        fibonacci[j+1]=fibonacci[j];
        fibonacci[j]=a;
      } 
    }
  }
  //------------------------------------------------

  for (int k=0; k<16; k++)
  {
    Serial.println(fibonacci[k]);
  }
}
```